# Is this a machine name or what?

Tags: dns, computer-name

I have a third party dll, that is supposed to return machine name.
Sometimes it returns

```
\\John-PC
```

some other times it returns

```
\\192.168.1.120
```

and recently i discovered that it returns something like this

```
\\[ef80::32d6:2255:27dd:123c]
```

So what is the third option?

If it is not a bug or MAC orelse, could i convert it to \192.168.1.120 and get happy???

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is the [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) version of the IPv4 address `192.168.1.120`
. It also amuses me how your DLL seems to be indecisive with what to return.

Comment: Well amusement has just stopped, since the machine name returns from the Marshal.PtrToStringUni method...

Answer (score 3):

It's an [IPv6](http://www.opus1.com/ipv6/whatdoesanaddresslooklike.html) address.  IPv6 allows you to leave out sections that are equal to 0, hence the `::`.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd option is a [IPv6 address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6)